# Query Expression by CRM Drop Down List value

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, dynamics-crm-4

In MS CRM 4, using c#, I am trying to query all accounts where a field that's picklist, is equal to "No". I know that picklists contain both an id and a value for each item but I want to query just for the value.

Here's my code currently:

```
ConditionExpression serviceContractCondition = new ConditionExpression();
        serviceContractCondition.AttributeName = "kez_servicecontracttype"; 
        serviceContractCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal; 
        serviceContractCondition.Values = new string[] { "Everything" };
```

In the code above im testing it by seeing if it can find only the accounts whos service contract type is equal to Everything (i changed the conditionOperator to equal). Instead of working i get this exception

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at crm.CrmService.Execute(Request Request) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\crmcustoms\3e2de0cf\f06ef1a\App_WebReferences.iwjjnsp-.0.cs:line 116 at crmCustoms.MetricFunctions.Retrieve_SC_Total() in e:\Projects\Kezber\crmCustoms\App_Code\MetricFunctions.cs:line 421

Server was unable to process request.

Comment: I follow the answer by Markus Palme, got the value of the picklist item by editing the picklist entry and then hard coded it like so serviceContractCondition.Values = new string[] { "2" }; now everything works.

Comment: My recommendtation would be to use constants or enumerations to avoid magic number in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklist items have a display label and an internal (numeric) value. First, you need to find the value that corresponds to `No`. The `MetadataService` allows you to do that. First, instantiate that service:

```
var metaservice = new MetadataService();.
metaservice.Url = "http://localhost/mscrmservices/2007/metadataservice.asmx";

metadata.Credentials = "same as you use for the crm webservice";
```

Then, use this method to retrieve the value of the picklist label:

```
int getPicklistValueByName(string picklistName, string entityLogicalName, string logicalName, MetadataService metaService)
{     
   RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
   attributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = entityLogicalName;
   attributeRequest.LogicalName = kogicalName;

   var attributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)metaService.Execute(attributeRequest);
   var picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;

   return picklist.Options.Where(op => op.Label.UserLocLabel.Label == picklistName).Single().Value.Value;
}
```

A call could looke like this:

```
var value = getPicklistValueByName("kez_servicecontracttype", "key_entitytype", "No", metaService)
```

Now, use this value in your condition expression. The alternative is to hardcode the numerical value as a constant in your program - which is better depends on your scenario.

Comment: We don't have the Metadata web reference added from crm, is there a way i can get the numerical value without the metaservice and just hardcode it as i believe this is how its been done before in our crm. If i go and edit the picklist entry "No" it says the value is 1.

Comment: Editing the picklist entry is exactly the way to find out the numerical value. So, yes you can hardcode that value into your program.